# Why can't I display an Image in a tkinter Toplevel() window?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create a python program tkinter that, upon the pressing of a button, opens a new full screen tkinter window containing an image and plays an audio file - here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from playsound import playsound

def play():
    window = Toplevel()
    window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pic.png"))
    label = Label(window, image=img).pack()
    playsound("song.mp3")
    
buttonWindow = Tk()
b = Button(buttonWindow, text="Press Button", command=play)
b.pack()
```

(my image and audio file are both on the desktop with my python file)

However, when I run my code, when I press the button, the audio plays but no second tkinter window opens.

I've tried to destroy() the buttonWindow and have tried many different ways of including an image on a tkinter window - if I remove the line of code using PhotoImage(), the window appears (obviously I then get a syntax error stating that 'img' is not defined).

How could I solve this?

Thanks,
Louis

Comment: For one thing, you shouldn't be calling `mainloop` inside of `play`. A tkinter app should only call `mainloop` once.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix it

Comment: The toplevel should be shown without the image because the image is garbage collected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your playsound() command is blocking execution. The playsound() command has an optional field 'block', which is True by default. Changing this to False will continue execution and allow mainloop() to continue.

Second, just call label.draw() to draw your image to the TopLevel window.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from playsound import playsound

def play():
    window = Toplevel()
    window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pic.jpeg"))
    label = Label(window, image=img).pack()
    playsound("song.mp3",block=False)
    label.draw()
    
buttonWindow = Tk()
b = Button(buttonWindow, text="Press Button", command=play)
b.pack()
buttonWindow.mainloop()
```

Cheers!

Comment: label inside `play()` is None because it is the result of `pack()` and also there is no `draw()` function for `Label` widget.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.
But i resolve this trial and error method.
First of all i don't use pillow library and put image into Label
You should try define Photoimage object NOT IN FUNCTION
Example:
It will work:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
def popUp():
    popff = tk.Toplevel(root)
    popff.geometry("400x200")
    labelImgff = tk.Label(popff, image=imgff, bg="white")
    labelImgff.grid(row=0, column=0)

imgff = tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/user/image.png")
btnff = tk.Button(text="startPOP", command=popUp)
btnff.grid(column=0,row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

[effect of action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyVh8.png)