# Opening another window by a button and returning an empty window using Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, pygame, mp3

The `grid()` can't draw the `Button` when other window is opening by clicking on another `Button`, returning just an empty window and an error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

I read a similar problem in another topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599709/why-cant-i-display-an-image-in-a-tkinter-toplevel-window)), but it happened with a `Label`, which it was solved using `.draw ()`. I wonder if there is a similar solution when the widget is a `Button`.
**PS**: I'm sure I placed the image path **correctly** from my project folder. The same image can be showed on the first button when running the program.

```py
from tkinter import *
import pygame

root = Tk()
root.title('Test')

def open_window():
    other_window = Tk()

    def play_sound():
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load('path.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        pygame.event.wait()

    bt_play_sound = Button(other_window, text = 'Play', image=img_play, command = play_sound, compound="top")
    bt_play_sound.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    other_window.mainloop()

#IMAGES
img_play = PhotoImage(file="path.png")

open_other_window = Button(root, text = "Open", image=img_play, command = open_window, compound="top")
open_other_window.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its not recommended to use more than one `Tk()` replace the child window with `Toplevel()`

Answer (score 1):

To get the second image to work, you need to create a new PhotoImage and specify the `master` option set to the second Tk window.

```
def open_window():
    other_window = Tk()

    def play_sound():
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load('path.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        pygame.event.wait()
        
    img_play = PhotoImage(file="path.png", master=other_window)    # <<<< Add this line
    bt_play_sound = Button(other_window, text = 'Play', image=img_play, command = play_sound, compound="top")
    bt_play_sound.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    
    other_window.mainloop()
```

As a side note, tkinter stores the images as strings (like keys in a dictionary). img_play = "pyimage1" (or whatever string tkinter assigns).